# How do i swap the Y axis (so that is starts at the bottom left of a winform) when dealing with control locations on winforms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have made a program that creates controls on a winform at runtime, and I am trying to export the Location (X/Y) to a label printer. The problem I am having is the Y axis on my label printer begins at the bottom left and in VS2017 it begins at the top left?

I have found a couple of previous questions related to tables / graphs, but did not find these applicable to my problem.

Comment: can you not just do (height of the form)-Y?

Comment: Printers have it at the top-left as well.  Is the text upside-down?

Comment: What about something like: `var TopMeasuredFromBottom = this.ClientRectangle.Bottom - control.Top;`